# How to check if value is an object in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

[jsBin Example](http://jsbin.com/orefASi/1/edit)

Here is my little model:

```
var stuff = [{
  there: 'blah',
  that: {
    one: 'bbb',
    two: 'ccc'
  }
}];
```

First, for the following template, I don't understand why the first `{{@key}}` doesn't output anything and the second one does.

```
{{#each this}}
  {{@key}}
  {{#each that}}
    {{@key}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

And more importantly I am trying to use this next template and a helper to check if a value is an object or a string and either iterate over it and print the keys, or just print out the key.

```
{{#each this}}
  {{#if isObj this}}
    {{#each that}}
      {{@key}}
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    {{@key}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isObj', function(thing) {
  return $.type(thing) === 'object';
});
```

Comment: To get the index of an array iteration you use `{{@index}}` for object keys you use `{{@key}}`. Normally you should know what you pass to the template. If you want to create a helper like `isObj` you would use it like this `{{#isObj this}} ... {{else}} ... {{/isObj}}` see [handlebars -  Conditionals](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#conditionals) for more details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first one I can answer, you should use `{{@index}}` instead of `{{@key}}` because your iterating an array. I'm looking into the second one.

A:

```
{{#each this}}
  key: {{@index}}
  {{#each that}}
    key1: {{@key}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

For part b it seems you're going to have to register a new helper function as if cant take the return from another funciton. You're block helper will be something like ([pretty much stole this from here](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/handlebars/base.js#L119)):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifObject', function(item, options) {
  if(typeof item === "object") {
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
  }
});
```

Now change your template to something like:

```
{{#each this}}
  {{#ifObject this}}
    {{#each that}}
      {{@key}}
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    {{@key}}
  {{/ifObject}}
{{/each}}
```

This was working on tryhandlebars.com and [updated your jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uROsAniP/3/edit), hope it helps!

Comment: ...block is not a function, do I have to pass that in, in the template?

Comment: Whoops I forgot to consider the else case in that helper

Comment: @RobertSadler I updated the partial - this is essentially copied from `#if` how works

Comment: mmk, so im working on http://jsbin.com/orefASi/1/edit -- it is only outputting 'one two', and i think i want 'there one two'

Comment: This strategy causes any string passed through it to return as an empty object. When I try to render `this` in an else block after verifying that it is not an object, it renders `[object Object]`, and logging it returns `{}`.


Immediately after typing this comment I realized my mistake. I changed the functions to arrow syntax, so I lost `this` binding. Leaving my shame here in case anyone else has this problem in the future.